# Kubernetes / External access from pod in GKE

Tags: kubernetes

I new in Kubernetes, and I created pods the following `yml` file:

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: myapp-act
  namespace: default
  labels:
    app: myapp
spec:
  replicas: 3
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: myapp
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: myapp
    spec:
      containers:
        - name: myapp
          image: myapp:latest
          envFrom:
          - configMapRef:
              name: map-myapp
```

The issue is that `myapp` is trying to query other apps which are located in my google project (as `GCE` machines) but are not part of the `GKE` cluster - without success.

i.e the issue is that I can't connect to the internal IP outside the cluster. I tried also to create `service` but it didn't fix the issue. all the information I found is how to expose my cluster to the world, but this is the opposite way.

what am I missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> the issue is that I can't connect to the internal IP outside the
>   cluster.

What you miss is called Ingress I believe.

> Ingress, added in Kubernetes v1.1, exposes HTTP and HTTPS routes from
>   outside the cluster to services within the cluster.

You can find more details and complete docs [here](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/ingress/).

**Update:** As you pointed out Ingress is a beta feature, but you can successfully use it if you are OK with the [limitations](https://github.com/kubernetes/ingress-gce/blob/master/BETA_LIMITATIONS.md#glbc-beta-limitations). Most likely you are, just go through the list. "Deployed on the master" means in my understanding that the ingress controller works on the k8s master node, a fact that should not normally bother you. What should you define next?

1.First you need to define a [service](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/connect-applications-service/#creating-a-service) which targets the pods in your deployment. It seems that you haven't done that yet, have you?

2.Then, on the next step, you need to create the Ingress, as shown in the docs, e.g.:

```
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: test-ingress
  annotations:
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/rewrite-target: /
spec:
  rules:
  - http:
      paths:
      - path: /testpath
        backend:
          serviceName: your-service-name
          servicePort: 80
```

Here `your-service-name` is the name of the service that you have already defined in point 1).

After you have done all this the backend service will be available outside of the cluser on a similar URL: https://.service..com

Comment: but I see that ```GCE/Google Kubernetes Engine deploys an ingress controller on the master. Review the beta limitations of this controller if you are using GCE/GKE``` 
what should I define here?

Answer (score 0):

In this case you should create an external service type with associated endpoint, like this:

```
kind: Endpoints
apiVersion: v1
metadata:
 name: mongo
subsets:
 - addresses:
     - ip: 10.240.0.4
   ports:
     - port: 27017
---
kind: Service
apiVersion: v1
metadata:
 name: mongo
Spec:
 type: ClusterIP
 ports:
 - port: 27017
   targetPort: 27017
```

Please refer to [this GCP blog post](https://cloud.google.com/blog/products/gcp/kubernetes-best-practices-mapping-external-services), that decribes very well in details the kubernetes best practices for mapping external services, living outside your cluster.